# Google maps, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I am fairly new to php and have not figured out how I would perform a certain task.

My code has the user input their address and then choose radius to
   search, after they search a map is generated that shows the 3 closest
   locations to their address.

I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the marker from the
   map it generates a page for that item clicked. saying you clicked on
   "store name". Could you please help me understand how this could be
   done? Thank you.

```
      <?php

    require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

    // Get parameters from URL
    $center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
    $center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
    $radius = $_GET["radius"];

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    // Opens a connection to a mySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
      die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active mySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Search the rows in the markers table
    $query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3",
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
      die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
      $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
      $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
    }

    echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

and

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }

   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }

   function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;

     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);
   }

   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations(); 

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }

    function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function parseXml(str) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
      } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
      }
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()"> 
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
    <select id="radiusSelect">
      <option value="3" selected>3mi</option>
      <option value="5">5mi</option>
      <option value="10">10mi</option>
      <option value="25">25mi</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" onclick="searchLocations();" value="Search"/>

    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:500;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500; height: 500"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it generates a page for that item clicked"? Do you want to generate a page asynchronous in the background or just open a page with a new url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS exist a global variable location. By changing the href attribute you can force the browser to open another url. docu: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

If you need information about the clicked marker you can put this information in a closure scope, to reuse it later when the marker is clicked. The create-function is called on runtime and the returned anonymous function is called by the click event.

Pseudocode:

```
function createCLickCallback(marker) {
    return function () {
        var position = marker.getPosition();
        location.href = "locationInfo.php?lat=" + position.lat() + "&lng=" + position.lng();
    };
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', createCLickCallback(marker));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your JS function "createMarker" you are adding listener to marker click event:
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
...
});
you should add your "page generation" code (whatever it is either open new page or update some part of current page) inside event callback function. In your current code google infowindow will be opened over your marker.